# How to let the user submit a picture (which is sent to my email) in a Wordpress site?

Tags: image, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site and I would like the user to be able to submit pictures which are sent to my email. Is there a plugin or a way of doing this? (the submission ins done in the front-end not in the back-end part).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a form plugin like [CForms](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/)?